# Resetting forms in Polymer 2.x

Tags: forms, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to reset my form. What am I doing wrong? What is best-practice?

[Here is my Plunk demo.](https://plnkr.co/edit/wRdXXws2UXl3VXrycqua?p=preview)

My problem on the demo is that `connectedCallback()` appears to fire continually (not just on initial load), thereby losing the value of `savedItem` by updating it to `newItem` on each update.

[Here is the same issue on Github.](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/issues/27)

https://plnkr.co/edit/wRdXXws2UXl3VXrycqua?p=preview

my-demo.html

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">


<dom-module id="my-demo">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host > * {
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      button.save {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-toggle-button checked="{{item.alice}}">Alice</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button checked="{{item.bob}}">Bob</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button checked="{{item.charlie}}">Charlie</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button checked="{{item.dave}}">Dave</paper-toggle-button>

    <button>Reset</button>
    <button class="save" on-tap="_reset">Save</button>

  </template>

  <script>
    class MyDemo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-demo';
      }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          item: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
            value: () => {
              return {
                alice: false,
                bob: false,
                charlie: false,
                dave: true,
              };
            },
          },
          savedItem: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
          },
        };
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.set('savedItem', this.item);
      }

      static get observers() {
        return [
          '_itemChanged(item.*)',
        ];
      }

      _itemChanged(newItem) {
        console.log('saved-item', this.savedItem);
        console.log('new-item', newItem);
      }

      _reset() {
        this.set('item', this.savedItem);
      }

    }

    window.customElements.define(MyDemo.is, MyDemo);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

## Edit

Steps to recreate the problem

1. [Open the demo here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/wRdXXws2UXl3VXrycqua?p=preview)
2. Open your console.
3. Navigate in the Plunker to my-demo.html
4. Click one of the toggle switches.
5. Notice in the console, the `savedItem` property updates to the current `item` property.
6. Notice, this appears to be the result of the following code block.

   ```
     connectedCallback() {
       super.connectedCallback();
       this.set('savedItem', this.item);
     }
   ```

But how can this be? Because I thought `connectedCallback()` only fired once at initialization time?

Comment: I don't see a repeated call of `connectedCallback()` in your demo. Is there code missing from the demo?

Comment: @tony19: Thank you for taking a look. I updated the demo and added an edit section to the bottom of the OP. That should clarify, hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** The `connectedCallback()` isn't actually being called more than once in this case. `savedItem` and `item` are always the same object in your code because JavaScript passes objects [by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

---

#### Object references

In the following:

```
connectedCallback() {
  this.set('savedItem', this.item);
}

_reset() {
  this.set('item', this.savedItem);
}
```

`savedItem` and `item` are both references to the same object. Calling `this.set()` does not automatically clone the operand (nor does the `=` operator).

One solution is to clone the object before assignment (using [ES2017 object-spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals)):

```
connectedCallback() {
  this.savedItem = {...this.item};
}

_reset() {
  this.item = {...this.savedItem};
}
```

[updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rB2fULYI2ipqLstNSPfm?p=preview)

---

#### Best practice (or simpler reset method)

A simpler way to reset the form is to let `iron-form` handle the form's `reset` event, where it resets the form's named inputs to their initial values. This saves you from having to declare `savedItem` and no extra JavaScript to manage it.

To accomplish this, wrap the `<paper-toggle-button>`'s in an `<iron-form>`, and add `name` attributes to them. Then, insert an `<input type="reset">` in the form, which serves as the reset button.

```
<iron-form>
  <form>
    <paper-toggle-button name="alice" checked="{{item.alice}}">Alice</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button name="bob" checked="{{item.bob}}">Bob</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button name="charlie" checked="{{item.charlie}}">Charlie</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button name="dave" checked="{{item.dave}}">Dave</paper-toggle-button>

    <input type="reset" class="save">
  </form>
</iron-form>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/n8Dr9gTGfhuNFJ3jNvAb?p=preview)

Comment: [A question on styling.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46617616/1640892) +1