# Styling native input in Polymer 2.x?

Tags: javascript, forms, polymer, polymer-2.x

[I am trying to implement this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615866/1640892)

Is there any way to bind an `on-click` or `on-tap` event of a `<paper-button>` to either of the following `hidden` `input` elements?

my-form.html

```
<iron-form>
  <form>
    ...
    <my-buttons></my-buttons>
    ...
    <input hidden type="reset">
    <input hidden type="submit">
  </form>
<iron-form>
```

Or to trigger those events in any way? i.e., I have dispatched an event from my `<paper-button>` as follows

my-buttons.html

```
<paper-button on-tap="_reset">Reset</paper-button>
<paper-button on-tap="_save">Save</paper-button>

<script>
  _reset() {
    // dispatchEvent...
  }
  _save() {
    // dispatchEvent...
  }
</script>
```

I want to give pretty (Material Design) styling to the buttons I display to the user of my `<iron-form>`.

[I am also watching @notwaldorf's (Monica D's) tutorial here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K76g5DGCBOk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need those hidden inputs, as `<iron-form>` provides an API for the equivalent events. Namely, [`<iron-form>.submit()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form/elements/iron-form#method-submit) and [`<iron-form>.reset()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form/elements/iron-form#method-reset):

```
// <iron-form id="form">

_reset() {
  this.$.form.reset();
}

_submit() {
  this.$.form.submit();
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rGJroe?editors=1010)